# ArrayFire is missing LAPACK - but I have it

Tags: opencl, lapack, arrayfire, lapacke

I just downloaded the latest release of [ArrayFire](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire) (3.3.1), and am trying to build it. I'm stuck at `cmake .` though. I installed a bunch of missing libraries, reran it, and now I get:

> ```
> -- Could NOT find LAPACK (missing:  LAPACK_LIBRARIES) 
> CMake Warning at src/backend/opencl/CMakeLists.txt:38 (MESSAGE):
>   LAPACK not found.  Functionality will be disabled
> ```

and

> ```
> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
> Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
> GLEWmxd_LIBRARY
>     linked by target "afcpu" in directory /home/joeuser/src/arrayfire-full-3.3.1/src/backend/cpu
>     linked by target "afcuda" in directory /home/joeuser/src/arrayfire-full-3.3.1/src/backend/cuda
>     linked by target "afopencl" in directory /home/joeuser/src/arrayfire-full-3.3.1/src/backend/opencl
> ```

I have installed lapack, and it's at /usr/lib/liblapack.so (that's an alternatives symlink, but it's not broken). Also installed lapacke.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more discriminating about what tags you put on your questions? This question and its solution clearly has nothing to do with CUDA in any non-trivial sense and it shouldn't have been tagged as a CUDA question.

Comment: I was under the false impression that lapacke had something to do with CUDA, that was wrong, sorry to whoever is monitoring the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArrayFire requires the LAPACKE library (On Ubuntu, liblapacke-dev, and the graphics part requires GLEW-MX (on Ubuntu, libglewmx-dev).

Comment: Well, I just installed every single package I could think of think of that seemed related, and then it worked somehow.